# Code Not Working (Trying to use != correctly)

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


int main ()
{
//Get Seed Color
string seedColor = "";
cout << "Enter Your Seed's Color: \n";
cin >> seedColor;
// Get Temp

if(seedColor != "red" || seedColor != "Red" && seedColor != "blue" || seedColor != "Blue")
    {
    cout << "Invalid Response. Please enter Red or Blue for the Color.\n";
    return 0;
    }

int temp = 0;
cout << "Enter Your Seed's Temperature: ";
cin >> temp;

 // if Red Seed
if(seedColor == "Red"|| seedColor == "red")
{


    //if temp >= 75
    if (temp >= 75)
    {

         // Get Soil Moisutre
        string soilMoisture = "";
        cout << "Enter Your Soil's Moisture (Wet or Dry): ";
        cin >> soilMoisture;

        // Soil Dry Output Dandelion
        if (soilMoisture == "Wet" || soilMoisture == "wet" )
        {
            cout << "A Sunflower will grow!\n";
        }

        if (soilMoisture == "Dry" || soilMoisture == "dry")
        {
            cout << "A Dandelion will grow!\n";
        }
    }


    else
    {
       // Otherwise Mushroom
       cout << "You will have a Mushroom!";
    }



}
// if Blue seed
if (seedColor == "Blue" || seedColor == "blue")
{


    //if temp b/t 60 && 70
    if (temp >= 60 && temp <= 70)
    {
        // Get Soil Moisutre
        string soilMoisture = "";
        cout << "Enter Your Soil's Moisture (Wet or Dry): ";
        cin >> soilMoisture;

        // Soil Dry Output Sunflower
        if (soilMoisture == "Dry" || soilMoisture == "dry")
        {
            cout << "A Sunflower will grow!";
        }
        // Soil Wet Output Dandelion
        if (soilMoisture == "Wet" || soilMoisture == "wet")
        {
            cout << "A Dandelion will grow! \n";
        }

    }
    else
    {
        // Otherwise Mushroom
        cout << "You will have a Mushroom! \n";
    }


}
    return 0;
}
```

Hey guys, So I'm having a bit of trouble trying to solve this issue. Whenever I run this code no matter if I put "Red" "Blue" or even something like "Bananas" it gives me the "Invalid Response" Prompt. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: You are using OR the wrong way around -- since at least *one* of the conditions is false (well, `true` because of the NOT equal), everything else is as well.

Comment: For starters, `&&` has higher precedence than `||`.

Comment: Probably not at all relevant but mushrooms don't grow from seeds.

Answer (score 2):

`if(seedColor != "red" || seedColor != "Red" && seedColor != "blue" || seedColor != "Blue")`

It may be easier to rewrite the `if` for acceptable seed colors first.  We know what is good, and for many programmers, the "good" condition is what's easiest to envision:

```
if( seedColor == "red" || seedColor == "Red" || 
    seedColor == "blue" || seedColor == "Blue")
{
   // this is a good seed color
}
else
{
   // this is a bad seed color
}
```

Now if you really wanted to test for the bad seed color, to turn it around requires just placing a `!` on the entire condition:

```
if(!(seedColor == "red" || seedColor == "Red" || 
    seedColor == "blue" || seedColor == "Blue") )
{
   // this is a bad seed color
}
else
{
   // this is a good seed color
}
```

There is a theorem called `Demorgan's Law`: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws

Applying it here would yield the following:

```
if (seedColor != "red" && seedColor != "Red" && 
    seedColor != "blue" && seedColor != "Blue")
{
   // this is a bad seed color
}
else
{
   // this is a good seed color
}
```

In other words, the `==` turn into `!=`, and the the `||` turn into `&&`.  So basically, we used a 3-step process to come up with the desired results, as per your question concerning `!=`:

1. Writing the "good condition"
2. Writing the bad condition by simply `not`ting the good condition.
3. Apply Demorgan's law to come up with the correct `!=` usage.

However, I would suggest that another way to do this is to write a function that returns "ok" if the seed color is good:

```
bool seedColorOk(const std::string& sColor)
{
   return seedColor == "red" || seedColor == "Red" || 
        seedColor == "blue" || seedColor == "Blue";
}
//...
if( !seedColorOk(seedColor))
{
   // this is a bad seed color
}
else
{
   // this is a good seed color
}
```

The function can then be customized without breaking your original code.

Answer (score 2):

If seedColor is "red" then seedColor != "Red" will be true.

If seedColor is "Red" then seedColor != "red" will be true.

If seedColor is anything else, then seedColor != "Red" and seedColor != "red" will both be true.

So whatever seedColor is, the expression seedColor != "red" || seedColor != "Red" will be true. Think about how you should combine the two subexpressions to get what you want.

And as was mentioned, && has higher precedence than ||, so there's another problem to fix.

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't mainly caused by != being off. Learn precedence of the logical operators here: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/36-logical-operators/ :D
Here's the "correct" way.(If this is your intended result)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


int main ()
{
//Get Seed Color
string seedColor = "";
cout << "Enter Your Seed's Color: \n";
cin >> seedColor;
// Get Temp

if((seedColor != "red" && seedColor != "Red") && (seedColor != "blue" || seedColor != "Blue"))
{
cout << "Invalid Response. Please enter Red or Blue for the Color.\n";
return 0;
}

int temp = 0;
cout << "Enter Your Seed's Temperature: ";
cin >> temp;

 // if Red Seed
if(seedColor == "Red"|| seedColor == "red")
{


//if temp >= 75
if (temp >= 75)
{

     // Get Soil Moisutre
    string soilMoisture = "";
    cout << "Enter Your Soil's Moisture (Wet or Dry): ";
    cin >> soilMoisture;

    // Soil Dry Output Dandelion
    if (soilMoisture == "Wet" || soilMoisture == "wet" )
    {
        cout << "A Sunflower will grow!\n";
    }

    if (soilMoisture == "Dry" || soilMoisture == "dry")
    {
        cout << "A Dandelion will grow!\n";
    }
}


else
{
   // Otherwise Mushroom
   cout << "You will have a Mushroom!";
}



}
// if Blue seed
if (seedColor == "Blue" || seedColor == "blue")
{


//if temp b/t 60 && 70
if (temp >= 60 && temp <= 70)
{
    // Get Soil Moisutre
    string soilMoisture = "";
    cout << "Enter Your Soil's Moisture (Wet or Dry): ";
    cin >> soilMoisture;

    // Soil Dry Output Sunflower
    if (soilMoisture == "Dry" || soilMoisture == "dry")
    {
        cout << "A Sunflower will grow!";
    }
    // Soil Wet Output Dandelion
    if (soilMoisture == "Wet" || soilMoisture == "wet")
    {
        cout << "A Dandelion will grow! \n";
    }

}
else
{
    // Otherwise Mushroom
    cout << "You will have a Mushroom! \n";
}


}
    return 0;
}
```